# .editorconfig file has no effect on code formatting in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I'm trying to get EditorConfig to work in VSCode.

I did the following:

- `npm i -g editorconfig`
- installed "EditorConfig for VSCode" extension
- added `.editorconfig` file to root

```
root = true    

[*]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```

- doesn't work, doesn't remove whitespace from a `.scss` file
- enabled "format on save"

  - still doesn't work
- closed and opened VSCode

  - still doesn't work
- checked to make sure the npm package was added: `npm list -g --depth=0`

  - yes: `+-- editorconfig@0.15.3`
  - still doesn't work

[image]

**What do I have to do to get EditorConfig to work in VSCode?**

Comment: This extension is really flaky. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does nothing at all.

Comment: I have same issue like you. What should we do to make it work?

Comment: i too have same issue. rules have no effect. Did anyone make it work here?